# Pandas datetime resample count non-zero

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a time series of daily rainfall data that looks like this:

```
                     PRCP
year_month_day           
1797-01-01 00:00:00   0.0
1797-01-02 00:00:00   0.0
1797-01-03 00:00:00   1.1
1797-01-04 00:00:00   0.0
1797-01-05 00:00:00   3.5
1797-02-01 00:00:00   8.1
1797-02-02 00:00:00   3.0
1797-02-03 00:00:00   0.0
1797-02-04 00:00:00   0.0
1797-02-05 00:00:00   0.0
1797-03-01 00:00:00   0.0
1797-03-02 00:00:00   0.0
1797-03-03 00:00:00   0.0
1797-03-04 00:00:00   0.0
1797-03-05 00:00:00   1.5
1797-04-01 00:00:00   6.3
1797-04-02 00:00:00  24.0
1797-04-03 00:00:00   0.0
1797-04-04 00:00:00   2.2
1797-04-05 00:00:00   5.9
1797-05-01 00:00:00   0.0
1797-05-02 00:00:00  15.9
1797-05-03 00:00:00   0.0
1797-05-04 00:00:00   0.0
1797-05-05 00:00:00   0.0
1797-06-01 00:00:00   1.6
1797-06-02 00:00:00   0.0
1797-06-03 00:00:00   0.0
1797-06-04 00:00:00   7.9
1797-06-05 00:00:00   0.0
```

I have been able to import it with the index column as a pandas datetime object. I am trying to count all of the non-zero raindays per month. I can group by month with:

```
grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
```

and can count everything per month with:

```
raindays = grouped.resample("M").count()
```

But that also counts days with 0 rainfall. I found hints about using `nunique()`, but it doesn't seem to work with resample. eg:

```
raindays = grouped.resample("M").nunique()
```

returns error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'nunique'
```

Is there a way to count non zero values in a grouped pandas object?

Comment: `df.resample('M').apply(lambda sdf: sdf.PRCP.ne(0).sum())` also should work. But masking first tends to be faster, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mask those 0s and try again.

```
df.mask(df.PRCP.eq(0)).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).count()
```

Or, the more obvious version with `replace`.

```
df.replace({0 : np.nan}).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).count()
```

```
                PRCP
year_month_day      
1797-01-31         2
1797-02-28         2
1797-03-31         1
1797-04-30         4
1797-05-31         1
1797-06-30         2
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know about mask. Very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `factorize` and `bincount`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.index + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0))
pd.Series(np.bincount(f, df.PRCP.values != 0).astype(int), u)

1797-01-31    2
1797-02-28    2
1797-03-31    1
1797-04-30    4
1797-05-31    1
1797-06-30    2
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. Any particular reason to chose this over the approach using `mask` offered by @coldspeed?

Comment: @Computarch should be pretty fast. I tend to think in this way. Only way to share that type of thinking is to show examples